# Getting user agent access in the resolver in graphql

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

I am relativity new to graphQL but this is annoying me. I want to get the user agent from the request body being sent from the client side. I can get access to the user-agent in the middleware however when I call the next function with any parameter to send to the resolver, I don't get any data from it. If I don't pass any parameters into next() then the resolver works as expected however parent, args, User and Session do not contain any information about the request headers. Any help or general tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

## app.js

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { graphiqlExpress, graphqlExpress } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';

import typeDefs from './Graphql/typeDefs';
import resolvers from './Graphql/resolver';

import { User } from './Mongoose/Schemas/user';
import { Session } from './Mongoose/Schemas/session';

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

const helperMiddleware = [
  bodyParser.json(),
  bodyParser.text({ type: 'application/graphql' }),
  (req, res, next) => {
    if ( req.body ) {
      console.log(req.headers['user-agent']);
    }
    next();
  },
];

const PORT = 3009;

const app = express();

app.use('/graphql', ...helperMiddleware, graphqlExpress({ schema, context: { User, Session } }));

app.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({ endpointURL: '/graphql' }));

app.listen(PORT);

console.log(`Running On Port ${PORT}`);
```

## resolver.js

```
  Mutation: {
    createUser: async (parent, args, { User, Session }) => {

      const user = await new User(args).save();
      user._id = user._id.toString();

      const session = await new Session({
        user_id: user._id,
        userAgent: 'Nothing ATM',
        ip: 'Nothing ATM',
      }).save();

      return user;
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the callback version of creating the GraphQL server middleware, otherwise you have no way of constructing context based on the current request:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/setup.html#options-function